# Who is The Sigilite?

Tags: warhammer-40k

I mean he is often described as second in psychic power to the Emperor.

Is The Sigilite a psychic double of the Emperor, his Brother or something else entirely? WHO is he? there is nothing about his origin. He just is!! That is why im asking is he the Emperor in disguise? A twin? ( Wich could explain Alparion/Omegon situation ). An early genetic experiment by the Emperor on himself??

Comment: Hm... I wanted to answer to your comment, but now it's gone. Anyway, now that you edited the question, I can see your intent more clearly, I appreciate that. As it stood before it was just too broad for my liking. Also, it wasn't my intention to attack or reprimand you (I happen to come across as rude, I'm told), but to clarify what you were asking exactly, so I apologize.

Answer (score 9):

**[Malcador the Sigillite](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Malcador_the_Sigillite) deemed Malcador the Hero by Imperial decree, was many things to the Imperium; advisor to the Emperor, Regent of the Empire, Master Administrator, establisher of parts of the Administratum, mystery, mutant and most importantly one of the greatest heroes of the Imperium.**

- Malcador was blessed with an extremely long life and superhuman vitality. He was one of the only purely human members of the Emperors primary court in the early days of the Imperium. No one knew of his true origins, save the Emperor of Man. He served as the primary advisor to the Emperor and served as Regent of the Imperium.
- It is rumored he was one of the first to have undergone the [Soul-Binding ritual](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Soul-Binding), the mark of a sanctioned psyker of the Imperium. His psychic powers were considered legendary, second only to the Emperor. He is also the only other psychic to ever have used the power of the Golden Throne to repel the forces of Chaos during the Horus Heresy.
- Malcador was the First Lord of Terra, who served as essentially the Emperor's Regent when he was away from Terra during the Great Crusade and the Horus Heresy eras. His name the Sigillite meant he was the "Seal-Bearer" and able to speak with the voice of the Emperor in all matters.
- A leader of men, he was credited with founding both the [Adeptus Administratum](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Adeptus_Administratum) of [Terra](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Terra) and the [Officio Assassinorum](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Officio_Assassinorum), as well as laying the foundations of the organisations that would become the Imperial [Inquisition](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Inquisition) and the [Grey Knights](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Grey_Knights). He also secretly served as the first Grand Master of Assassins of the [Officio Assassinorum](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Officio_Assassinorum).
- He was responsible for the creation of the [Chaplain](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Chaplains) class, a specialist officer of the Adeptus Astartes. Chaplains were the spiritual leaders of a Space Marine Chapter. Powerful priest who lead from the front as awe-inspiring examples of the values and beliefs of the chapter exhorting their battle-brothers to greater feats of bravery.
- Though his mind was powerful, using the Throne while the Emperor and his loyal guard repelled the final forces of Chaos, Malcador expended the last of his psychic energy and life-force to bring the Emperor from his coma, long enough to give his last instructions before he was bound to the Golden Throne, forever.

Malcador is one of the greatest Human heroes of the Imperium, having established many of the resources currently in use which sustain the Imperium even into the Modern Era, and it was with his sacrifice the Golden Throne continues to sustain the Imperium even in these dark times. All hail Malcador the Hero!

Comment: Again you supprise me with you wall of text skills Thaddeus!! long live Lexicanum page. :-)  While i appreciate it immensely you do not answer my question in any way, shape or form. I have +1 your answer but i cant give it an answered mark.

Answer (score 2):

[Malcador the Sigillite](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Malcador_%28Character%29) was an extremely powerful psyker (though much weaker than the Emperor himself) and the closest advisor of the Emperor during the Great Crusade and the Horus Heresy. He acted as regent of the Empire during the time the Emperor was occupied with the creation of the Golden Throne, and actually took the Emperor's place on it during the final battle against Horus, an ordeal he did not survive.

It is rumoured but not known definitely that Malcador was a relative of the Emperor.

Comment: hmm... Whenever the Emperor is about there is no sight of the Sigilite and the other way around. Cant remebmer even 1 occurance where both are portrayed so im wondering if they were 2 sides of the same coin. Did the Emperor choose to "create" Malcador and in doing so make it possible to do and hear things that he himself couldn't. I mean in the current cannon it takes 10.000 psykers to keep the Astronomicon alive every day! That means the Sigilite was "at least" Alpha ++ level psyker.

Comment: @Cherubel: Malcador only had to keep the Warp demons out of  the Golden Throne and parts of the Webway, not project a beacon across the entire galaxy. Additionally, the Golden Throne's technology has degraded significantly since then.

Comment: @Cherubel "Whenever the Emperor is about there is no sight of the Sigilite and the other way around" - They were both present at the same time on Khur, when the Word Bearers were censured. They are also in the same room in the novel Nemesis, towards the end.

Comment: @Cherubel They are also both present at the Council of Nicaa.